# Implications of long session time-out in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, session-state

We are planing to increase the time-out on the session in our applications.
Currently we have 3 hours.

What are the pitfalls of the one week or more session time-out?

What we have

- SqlSessionStateStore (MsSql server 2005)
- 5-10 k unique page views per day (@updated)
- No authentication

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it the same 5,000 visitors every day or new visitors?

Comment: @Dallas unique page views in busiest days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implications will be that since everytime a new user opens a new browser window he will create a new session which will be persisted in SQL Server for 1 week which potenatially could greatly increase the size of the database. This will not happen if the users keep their browsers open for 1 week since they will not be creating new sessions.

I think that if you need to persist some data for 1 week the Session is not the right storage location for you.